# 500 Internal Server Error when installing magento2.2.2

Tags: magento2, installation, magento2.2.2, http-error-500

I am trying to install Magento 2.2.2 on my local Windows environment with WAMP. But it gives me a *500 Internal Server Error*. When I replace the previous version of `htaccess` file it does work. Would that be the issue?

Rewrite engine is on and the module is loaded.

Error log:

```
Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I have tried to enable `LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so` to make it work but now when the installation runs, in between it responds in my console that it's `false` after a few seconds. When I try to refresh, it starts the remaining installation but I have to refresh several times to complete the installation. I don't know if Magento is installed successfully or not during this process.

When I go to the admin it works, but I get console JS errors. The front-end still loads without CSS.

I tried to install it several times but every time I wind up with this error

Comment: Could you please share the htaccess file as well as the log-file that details the error?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok Finally.... here is the process i did follow to get rid from this.

**Step1::** Please make sure that `LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so` is loaded from `httpd.conf` file to resolve `Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration` error.

**Step2::**

Please make sure that below variable value should be set as

```
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = 1800
memory_limit = 1024M
```

**Step3::(Optional)**

Creat virtual host.

add below code in your file path :: `D:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

Path may vary as per your installation

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName demomage222
ServerAlias www.demomage222.com
DocumentRoot D:/wamp64/www/mage222
<Directory  "/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
```

Make entry in host file like below.
host file path for me(may different for you) :: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 www.demomage222.com
```

Comment: +1 for your post , its help me to resolve the issue !! special Loadmodule mod_version.so needs to be enabled !! Thank you once again

Comment: It works for me

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue when i was installing Magento 2.2 on WAMP. I changed the PHP version to PHP 7.1 and then restarted the installation. Things worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Locate `Options +FollowSymLinks` in `.htaccess` of your Magento root and change it to: `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`

Do that for `/pub/static/.htaccess` and `/pub/media/.htaccess` as well.

**EDIT**

The described error points to mod_version not being enabled.

To enable it go to `http.conf` in the `conf` folder and find a line that has mod_version in it.

Remove "#" from the beginning to uncomment it.

Then restart apache.

Comment: changed but nothing happen

Comment: You should check the php error log then and post it's contents. It should be located here: ...\wamp\logs\error.log

Comment: it gives error in log like `Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing it **while installation** it could be **A Permissions Error**.

In most cases, a 500 Internal Server Error is due to an incorrect permission on one or more files or folders. set folder permission to 0775

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /path_to_magent/Folder
```

Comment: Doesnt apply here as windows