# Static files - 500 error

Tags: javascript, css, magento2.2.2

I installed fresh Magento but there are no styles or js. Files are in pub folder , but if open in browser I'm getting Internal Server Error. Please help. This is localhost, wamp. Thank you!
(I tried clear cache and remove directories in var and pub)

[image]

---

I found the answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/208638/34234

Comment: Maybe this will helpful for you.
<https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder>

Comment: Can you please check pub/static/.htaccess file is there or not, if not then copy from the setup and past it over there and check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run static content depolyment comment in your server.

Use the following comment

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Clear cache and set correct folder permission

OR

When Magento 2 is not in production mode, it will try to create symlinks for some static resources on local server. We have to change that behavior of Magento 2 by going to edit ROOT > app > etc > di.xml file. Open up di.xml in your favorite code editor, find the virtualType name="developerMaterialization" section. In that section below, you will find an item  which needs to be modified. You can modify it by changing the following content:

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

To:

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Now last step, also delete old files generated in ROOT > pub > static > DELETE ALL EXCEPT .HTACCESS

Answer (score 0):

The 500 status code means that there is an error. Have you tried to look in the network tab how the preview of the response looks like or in a new window or browser tab?

Perhaps you have to enable display_errors first.

Besides that set the deploy mode to developer to get client side static files rendering or deploy the static content

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a cPanel and/or WHM, depending on your settings you may need to remove the .htaccess from the [magento_root]/pub/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using WAMPServer with Apache 2.4. For some reason, Apache on here doesn't recognize `<IfVersion`. So, in addition to running `./bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, remove those `<IfVersion` rules from .htaccess and pub/.htaccess, and that's gotten rid of my 500 errors.